# How to make `FloatingActionButton`s, `TextButton`s and `IconButton`s look the same in means of size, shape and color, using a theme in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I want that the `FloatingActionButton`s, `TextButton`s and `IconButton`s will be visually consistent, thus look the same in means of size, shape and color, using a theme in Flutter. how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

For defining a theme, MaterialApp has a property named theme. There you have to provide the instance of ThemeData.

```
MaterialApp(
title: title,
theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
  )
);
```

For "FloatingActionButton", "IconButton" and "TextButton" to look like same you have to define the theme (all the properties which you want to be consistent) for all of them such as.

For IconButton

```
iconTheme: IconThemeData(
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
```

For FloatingActionButton

```
floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
    foregroundColor: Colors.red,
  ),
```

For TextButton

```
textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.red,
  ),
),
```

**My Suggestion:**
Use the primarySwatch property for the consistent color scheme.

```
primarySwatch: Colors.red;
```